# Use string in multiple React templates in a Meteor project?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Im using Meteor with React. I have a string (a URL) that I need to use in multiple templates. How can I make a variable that can be passed around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe create (if you don't really have one) a settings.json file, and store the URL inside ?

```
{
  "public": {
    "resizeUrl": "https://res.cloudinary.com/account-name/image/fetch/"
  }
}
```

And then you could use Meteor.settings.public.resizeUrl;

Comment: Its a url for resizing images: https://res.cloudinary.com/account-name/image/fetch/. Its not content or state really, its part of the application.

Comment: It would make senes for this value to be in version control, which it wont be if its in settings.

Comment: But if you have a settings-development.json and a settings-production.json and you only omit the production file from the version control?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a javascript file with vars:

In vars.js:

```
export const imgResizeUrl = 'www.something.com/';
```

In the file that needs to use the variable:

```
import { imgResizeUrl } from '../vars';

<img src={`${imgResizeUrl}/my-image`} alt="" />
```